# jQuery Autocomplete can not append dropdown from ajax result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using craftyclicks postcode lookup API which return result via ajax and append them.
I have checked all library files as well,but there is no issue with that.
It returns response in JSON which is okay but can't append to my textbox.
I checked all possible ways still it is not woking
Below is my code

```
jQuery("#post_code").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var enable_search = true;
        if(enable_search){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "https://pcls1.craftyclicks.co.uk/json/rapidaddress",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    postcode: jQuery("#post_code").val(),
                    response: 'data_formatted',
                    lines: '2',
                    sort: 'asc',
                    key: "asdasd-asdasd-asdasd-asdasd"
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.error_code != undefined){
                        //handle error message
                        alert(data.error_msg);
                    }
                    else{
                        var clear_data = new Array();
                        jQuery.each( data.delivery_points, function( index, item ) {
                            var fullLabel = item.department_name;

                            if(fullLabel != '' && item.organisation_name != '')
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + ', ' + item.organisation_name;
                            else
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + item.organisation_name;

                            if(fullLabel != '' && item.line_1 != '')
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + ', ' + item.line_1;
                            else
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + item.line_1;

                            if(fullLabel != '' && item.line_2 != '')
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + ', ' + item.line_2;
                            else
                                fullLabel = fullLabel + item.line_2;

                            clear_data.push({
                                town: data.town,
                                postcode: data.postcode,
                                pcounty: data.postal_county,
                                tcounty: data.traditional_county,
                                dep_name: item.department_name,
                                line_1: item.line_1,
                                line_2: item.line_2,
                                org: item.organisation_name,
                                udprn: item.udprn,
                                label: fullLabel,
                                value: data.postcode
                            });
                        });
                        response( clear_data );
                    }
                }
            });
            enable_search = 0;
        }
    },
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {

        jQuery("#town").val(ui.item.town);

        if(ui.item.line_1!='' && ui.item.line_2 != ''){
            jQuery("#address1").val(leading_caps(ui.item.line_1 +', '+ ui.item.line_2));
            var add1 = (leading_caps(ui.item.line_1 +', '+ ui.item.line_2));
        }else{
            jQuery("#address1").val(leading_caps(ui.item.line_1 + ui.item.line_2));
            var add1 = (leading_caps(ui.item.line_1 + ui.item.line_2));
        }

        jQuery("#post_code").val(ui.item.postcode);
        jQuery("#companyname").val(ui.item.org);

        //var div_data="<option>"+ui.item.org+", "+add1+", "+ui.item.town+"</option>";
        //jQuery(div_data).appendTo('#ch_user1'); 

        // do any action on selecting a result
    },
    open: function() {
        // do any action on showing the results
    },
    close: function() {
        jQuery("#post_code").autocomplete({ disabled: true });
        jQuery("#post_code").blur();
        // do any action on closing the results
    }
});
```

Comment: Looking over this, I suspect that this is missing `return false;` in the `select` callback.

Comment: @Twisty...thank you